# SurfaceView getting stretched Android

Tags: android

I'm using SurfaceView as a part of my Activity (Please see the screenshot below) in my Android app, for that I have written the following code-

My XML Code is---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/createReviewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_gradient" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reviewedItemImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/review_gradient"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.wikireviews.util.InfiniteViewPager
            android:id="@+id/categoryPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/two_thirty"
            android:background="@color/trending_theme_color" >
        </com.wikireviews.util.InfiniteViewPager>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/categoryPager"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/writeReviewLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/create_rev_item_clr" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/pencil" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/writeReviewTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/write_a_review"
                    android:textColor="@color/create_rev_item_txt_clr"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dictateReviewLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/writeReviewLayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/create_rev_item_clr" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/dictate" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dictateReviewTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/dictate_review"
                    android:textColor="@color/create_rev_item_txt_clr"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlVidRevParentLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/dictateReviewLayout"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/one_hundred_twenty"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

                <SurfaceView
                    android:id="@+id/videoSurface"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/videoReviewLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/create_rev_item_clr" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/video" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/videoReviewTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/video_review"
                        android:textColor="@color/create_rev_item_txt_clr"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLblHoldRec"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/rlVidRevParentLayout"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/rlVidRevParentLayout"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/rlVidRevParentLayout"             
                android:textSize="@dimen/sz_ten"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hold_rec_to_record_video" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        layout="@layout/footer" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/create_reviews_header" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/createRevProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        layout="@layout/progressbar_medium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java Code is--

```
cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
        cameraView = new CameraView();

        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = cameraSurfaceView.getHolder();
        try 
        {
            //surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(cameraSurfaceView.getWidth(), cameraSurfaceView.getHeight());
            //surfaceHolder.setSizeFromLayout();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(cameraView);
            surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.d("debug", "Another exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For more detail please see the screenshot below--
[image]

Actual Image is Like this--
[image]

I searched a lot but yet not found any acceptable solution. Please Help.

Comment: In rlVidRevParentLayout you set height to 120 so your surface view takes 120 as height and match_parent as width. change Height of rlVidRevParentLayout according to your needs.

Comment: Does the image skewed? It seems Image is just stretched horizontally to match the parent. Please add the image what the View should look like.

Comment: @Suhyeon Lee Plz check my edited question.

Comment: @LeoWiki So it's not skewed, it's just scaled by Y axis. So you wanna keep the SurfaceView size like first image and scale down actual image to fit center-inside in your SurfaceView?

Comment: @LeoWiki Oh I'm wrong. It skewed like you said. hmm that's weird...